# Javacard Webapplication how to install *.war file

Tags: war, javacard

I am new in JavaCard development, and I am quite confused.

I am able to compile, load and install .cap files, and everything works fine.

However, after compiling my WebApplication (with NetBeans), I am not sure how to load/convert/install the produced .war file to the card.

Any help much appreciated!

edit:

I realized I should had provided more info:
My card is: J2E145G, which if I am not mistaken supports version 3.0 (and hence is the "connected" edition?). Additionally, I am loading applets using GlobalPlatform, which it seems that supports only .cap files(?)

Comment: If your card is a Classic Edition Java Card, then you won't load and install any .war file. You almost always load and install .cap files. Netbeans also generate a .cap file from your project.

Comment: @Abraham Thanks for the response! I updated the original post to include more info. It seems that netbeans doesn't generate a .cap file, unless I select a "classic applet" project. However, I want to use the web capabilities of the card (assuming that it actually has them).

Comment: There is two different type of specificatios for Java Card 3.* . A _Classic Edition_ version and a _Connected Edition_ version. The web capability is one of the features of _Connected Edition_ only. As far as I know, all the available nowadays cards are based on _Classic Edition_ specification. So you haven't this capability available on nowaday cards.

Comment: The applet loading and installation mechanism responsibility is dedicated to Global Poatform spec (And not Java Card spec), And as we don't have any real JC Connected Edition, it is not documented yet in GP specification that how to load and install war files, I guess.

Comment: Cheers man, makes sense now. It seems that there are few engineering samples going around, but I wasn't able to find an actual product. However, people are giving lectures on "development for connected JavaCards", and this makes me suspicious, that there are products somewhere. I guess if I want accessing my card from a browser my options are limited...

Answer (score 2):

I presume J2E145G (I'm not sure about the G, I can check later) contains the P5Cx family of products of NXP. These cards sport 8 KiB of RAM and are therefore incapable of running the connected edition, which requires 24 to 32 KiB of RAM.

These kind of humongous chips (for smart card standards anyway) are usually found on contact only cards. To say that connected edition chips are not common is probably taking it lightly.

Comment: +1 : Let assume that a card is supporting Connected Edition, then is there any standardized way to install applets on them?

Comment: My understanding currently is that there are no commercial cards supporting the Connected Edition. Are they? I am only interested in developing a prototype so I will just need 1-5 cards, but then as @Abraham said, it seems that there is a gap on how to install etc applets on them.